# Is Keycloak experiencing memory leak?

Tags: postgresql, memory-leaks, out-of-memory, heap-memory, keycloak

i'm using Keycloak as Identity Manager for the solution i'm working on and in the last months i started experiencing periodically an out of memory error after aproximatly two weeks.

> Uncaught server error: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError:Java heap space

I tried different version of keycloak from 13 to 15 but it doesnt seem to make any difference.
I started investigating in a docker environment where i only run keycloak and postgres and leave everything idle.

This is the docker-compose.yml file i used to setup the environment:

```
version: '3'

services:

  postgres:
      image: postgres:14.1
      environment:
        POSTGRES_DB: keycloak
        POSTGRES_USER: postgres
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
        
  keycloak:
      image: jboss/keycloak:15.1.0
      environment:
        DB_VENDOR: POSTGRES
        DB_ADDR: postgres
        DB_DATABASE: keycloak
        DB_USER: postgres
        DB_SCHEMA: public
        DB_PASSWORD: password
        KEYCLOAK_USER: admin
        KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: password
      ports:
        - 8080:8080
      depends_on:
        - postgres
```

In the meantime i also launched a standalone container of Keycloak not persisting on Postgres.

I left the containers idle and started monitoring the memory required by Keycloak, these are the results:

| Time | Keycloak + Postgres | Keycloak |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11:50 | 630 MB | 640 MB |
| 11:55 | 630.1 MB | 645 MB |
| 12:00 | 630.2 MB | 646.5 MB |
| 12:10 | 630.3 MB | 653 MB |
| 12:30 | 630.6 MB | 654.5 MB |
| 12:40 | 630.7 MB | 655.1 MB |
| 14:30 | 631 MB | 655.5 MB |

I know the "leak" is almost inconsistent... any ideas on how i could verify if this is actually a leak and in case it is if it is responsible for keycloak out of memory error after weeks of execution? Anyway thanks for your help.

**UPDATE**

As suggested i modified docker compose file specifying memory reservation and limit for keycloak and postgres services as follows:

```
version: '3'

services:

  postgres:
      image: postgres:14.1
      environment:
        POSTGRES_DB: keycloak
        POSTGRES_USER: postgres
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
      deploy:
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: 2G
          reservations:
            memory: 1G
        
  keycloak:
      image: jboss/keycloak:15.1.0
      environment:
        DB_VENDOR: POSTGRES
        DB_ADDR: postgres
        DB_DATABASE: keycloak
        DB_USER: postgres
        DB_SCHEMA: public
        DB_PASSWORD: password
        KEYCLOAK_USER: admin
        KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: password
      ports:
        - 8080:8080
      depends_on:
        - postgres
      deploy:
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: 1G
          reservations:
            memory: 650M
```

To monitor memory usage i used `docker stats` command, with system in idle the memory usage of keycloak container keeps slightly growing over time.

Comment: I don't see a leak. I also don't see any memory limit for the Keycloak, so it is possible that some other app on the server allocated too much memory and then Keycloak doesn't have memory when it needs it. So set memory limit, configure java heap size explicitly (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53451103/java-using-much-more-memory-than-heap-size-or-size-correctly-docker-memory-limi/53602861#53602861) - also it is not clear what do you measure with your memory metric. There is many types of "memory" - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15487506/questions-about-linux-memory-types